# Salesforce Sites. In the context of which user, operations are performed on the site?

Tags: salesforce, settings

I can not find the exact information on this issue. Can someone help and clarify the situation.

I heard something about the guest user, but can't find the information.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking

Comment: It's about Salesforce Sites. Is this information enough?

Comment: Not really. What does this mean? "In the context of which user, operations are performed on the site?"

Comment: Some guy deleted my answer and left you astray but what you're looking for is this https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.financial_services_cloud_admin_guide.meta/financial_services_cloud_admin_guide/fsc_admin_create_customer_community_user_profile.htm

real courteous of https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters